# "Can you call me back soon" or "Can you call me soon?"

Tags: word-choice

In these sentences:

"Can you call me back soon?"

"Can you call me soon?"

Is the "back" redundant and should it be omitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both are right but you usually say :

"Can you call me back soon?"

when you are speaking to someone over phone and you need to hang up. then you say call me **back**

and otherwise you simply say : "can you call me soon ?"

Answer (score 1):

"Call me soon" doesn't necessarily imply a phone call is taking place at present, but "Call me back" does, and it implies that a secondary call should follow shortly.

You can tell someone "call me soon!" without actually being on the phone with them, to indicate you wish to be called by them.  But you could not say "call me back soon!" in the same manner.

If you are on the phone and the person you have called indicates that they need to hang up, you could then tell them to "call me back soon!" to indicate that you wish for them to call you in return at some point in the near future once the call is over.  "Call me soon" means almost the same thing, but the addition of 'back' helps to indicate that the next call should be in response to the first one.

Answer (score -1):

The "*back*" is not redundant, it implies a second phone call with a follow up conversation about the current topic.

"*Call me soon*" just means that there should be another call, but it could be about something unrelated.